# why we recommend iterators instead of lists (low-level explanation)

Tags: python, list, iterator

I know that this question have been asked a lot of times here and outside. But I steel trying to figure out why we recommend the use of iterators but not lists when we have large dataset.

In this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/628903/performance-advantages-to-iterators), people talking about memory and time advantages of using iterators instead of lists but without giving a low-level arguments.

In the [mail](http://markmail.org/message/t2a6tp33n5lddzvy) pointed by the accepted answer, it's written:

> Iterators have a tiny constant size while lists take space proportional to the length of the list. The part that is not obvious is that looping over the iterator re-uses the same memory location again an again. So the relevant data is almost always in the hardware memory cache.

But why does iterators takes a tiny constant size and why is looping over the iterator re-uses the same memory location again an again?

Comment: in the same post Christian Witts says *XRange just has a generator object and yields the next item when needed instead.* The answer is already given in the OP.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Performance Advantages to Iterators?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/628903/performance-advantages-to-iterators)

Comment: Hi @UmNyobe, thank you for the comment, so where the iterator data is stored?

Comment: I don't understand your question. You want a low-level discussion of the Python internals, but you link to just such a discussion on the mailing list. And questions like "why does looping over the iterator re-use the same memory location again and again" are answered almost with: "Because." That's a performance optimization the Python team made. Why? Because, as the mail discussion notes, it keeps things in the hardware memory cache for faster access.

Comment: @UmNyobe I pointed that question -___-

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist: Sorry for the possible lack of clarity. So I am asking: (1) How the iterator structure can optimize the time and memory usage. and (2) why  looping over the iterator re-uses the same memory location again an again.

Comment: @farhawa It's fine. I basically think you have answered your own question but something about it still has not "clicked" and I'm trying to figure out what that is. (1.) The entirety of a list is stored in memory, all at once. Regardless of length or what it contains, it's all there. Iterators and generators need only know how to get the _next_ item. This even allows for potentially _infinite_ collections, which obviously is not possible with lists without infinite RAM. (2.) As I said, this is a deliberate decision by the Python team to improve performance for reasons already stated.

Comment: It looks like the question really is `what is an iterator?`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But why does iterators takes a tiny constant size and why is looping over the iterator re-uses the same memory location again an again?

Let's say you are reading lines from a file.  If you were to create a *list* from all the lines in the file:

```
lines = myfile.readlines()
for line in lines:
    ...
```

...this loads the entire file into memory.  If the file is sufficiently large, you will consume allt he available memory and your program will crash.

On the other hand, if you use the iterator:

```
for line in myfile:
   ...
```

Then Python only needs to read in enough data to find the next EOL character.  This uses *substantially* less memory as long as you are working with a line-oriented file (if the file has no EOL characters, then of course there is no advantage in this example).

The same reasoning applies, for example, to `xrange()` vs `range()` (where the latter returns a *list*, which will consumes a large number of resources if the range is large, while the former only needs to maintain a counter).