# Avoid bulk data export into csv when the header is dynamic

Tags: python, csv, stream, python-3.6

I stumbled across a very simple situation which I cannot seem to find a solution for.

What I want to do is simple: write some data into a *.csv* file containing:

- a *dynamic* header
- some data

The way I'm doing it right now seems to be the only solution that I could come up with:

- store the data that I need in a list of dictionaries
- get the `keys()` of every dictionary in the above list and add them to a `set()` (this will be the header)
- write the data to the file using `writer.writerows(data)`

Basically, a simple *MCVE* might look like this:

```
from csv import DictWriter

RESULT_FILE = 'test_result.csv'


def get_fieldnames(data):
    fieldnames = set()
    for item in data:
        fieldnames.update(item.keys())
    return fieldnames


def main(data):
    fieldnames = get_fieldnames(data)

    with open(RESULT_FILE, 'a', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        writer = DictWriter(f, fieldnames=fieldnames, delimiter=',')
        writer.writeheader()
        writer.writerows(data)


if __name__ == '__main__': 
    data_ = [
        {
            'a': '1',
            'b': '2',
            'c': '3',
        },
        {
            'a': '6',
            'd': '1',
            'b': '3',
        },
        {
            'c': '2',
            'e': '1',
            'f': '9',
        }
    ]
    main(data_)
```

Now, what I don't like about this:

- The list might become extremely large (~100k dicts / each dict containing around 10 fields).
- If the program crashes when the 66666 dict is added to the list, everything is lost and I also don't have any data in the *csv*. Because I have to wait for all the data to be added to the list to get all the possible headers, I couldn't avoid this scenario.

How can I avoid exporting all the data at once in the csv when the header is dynamic?

---

As requested, the real data looks like this:

```
{'Catalog link': '',
 'Category': 'Tools and Shop Supplies / Workshop Accessories / Tool '
             'Accessories / Sander Accessories',
 'Description': 'Exclusive single-piece hub design reduces pad vibration and '
                'ensures smooth performance.',
 'Each': '$ 24.70',
 'Info': '',
 'Line art': '',
 'Name': '(5") Non-Vacuum Disc Pad Vinyl-Face',
 'Product number': '91456106T',
 'Technical specifications': '',
 'image_1': 'https://www.richelieu.com/documents/docsGr/120/107/6/1201076/1419675_700.jpg'}

{'Catalog link': '',
 'Category': 'Tools and Shop Supplies / Workshop Accessories / Tool '
             'Accessories / Sander Accessories',
 'Description': '',
 'Each': '$ 8.19',
 'Info': '<p><strong>material: </strong>Cork</p>',
 'Line art': '',
 'Name': 'Replacement Plate for MKT9924DB Belt Sander',
 'Product number': 'MKT4230358',
 'Technical specifications': '<p><strong>brand: </strong>Makita</p>',
 'image_1': 'https://www.richelieu.com/documents/docsGr/116/631/4/1166314/1281513_700.jpg',
 '\xa0': '$ 257.80'}

{'Catalog link': '',
 'Category': 'Tools and Shop Supplies / Workshop Accessories / Tool '
             'Accessories / Sander Accessories',
 'Description': '',
 'Each': '$ 8.19',
 'Info': '<p><strong>material: </strong>Graphite</p>',
 'Line art': '',
 'Name': 'Replacement Plate for MKT9924DB Belt Sander',
 'Product number': 'MKT4230366',
 'Technical specifications': '<p><strong>brand: </strong>Makita</p>',
 'image_1': 'https://www.richelieu.com/documents/docsPr/MK/T4/23/03/66/MKT4230366/1281514_700.jpg',
 '\xa0': '$ 257.80'}

{'Catalog link': '',
 'Category': 'Tools and Shop Supplies / Workshop Accessories / Tool '
             'Accessories / Sander Accessories',
 'Description': '- Exclusive single-piece hub design reduces pad vibration and '
                'ensures smooth performance.',
 'Each': '$ 38.47',
 'Info': '',
 'Line art': '',
 'Name': 'Non-Grip Vacuum Pads',
 'Product number': '9154325',
 'Technical specifications': '<p><strong>thickness: </strong>3/8 '
                             'in</p><p><strong>density: '
                             '</strong>Medium</p><p><strong>nap: '
                             '</strong>Short</p>',
 'image_1': 'https://www.richelieu.com/documents/docsPr/91/54/32/5/9154325/1213330_700.jpg',
 'image_2': 'https://www.richelieu.com/documents/docsPr/91/54/32/5/9154325/1213331_700.jpg'}

{'Catalog link': '',
 'Category': 'Tools and Shop Supplies / Workshop Accessories / Tool '
             'Accessories / Sander Accessories',
 'Description': '- Exclusive single-piece hub design reduces pad vibration and '
                'ensures smooth performance.',
 'Each': '$ 52.92',
 'Info': '',
 'Line art': '',
 'Name': 'Non-Grip Vacuum Pads',
 'Product number': '9154327',
 'Technical specifications': '<p><strong>thickness: </strong>3/8 '
                             'in</p><p><strong>density: '
                             '</strong>Medium</p><p><strong>nap: '
                             '</strong>Short</p>',
 'image_1': 'https://www.richelieu.com/documents/docsGr/105/122/1/1051221/1213328_700.jpg',
 'image_2': 'https://www.richelieu.com/documents/docsPr/91/54/32/7/9154327/1213332_700.jpg'}

{'Catalog link': '',
 'Category': 'Tools and Shop Supplies / Workshop Accessories / Tool '
             'Accessories / Sander Accessories',
 'Description': '- Unique one-piece hub design reduces pad vibration and '
                'ensures smooth performance.',
 'Each': '$ 26.84',
 'Info': '',
 'Line art': '',
 'Name': 'Stick-on Non-Vacuum Pads',
 'Product number': '9156106',
 'Technical specifications': '<p><strong>thickness: </strong>3/8 '
                             'in</p><p><strong>density: </strong>Medium</p>',
 'image_1': 'https://www.richelieu.com/documents/docsGr/105/122/4/1051224/1213343_700.jpg',
 'image_2': 'https://www.richelieu.com/documents/docsPr/91/56/10/6/9156106/1213345_700.jpg'}

{'Catalog link': '',
 'Category': 'Tools and Shop Supplies / Workshop Accessories / Tool '
             'Accessories / Sander Accessories',
 'Description': '- Unique one-piece hub design reduces pad vibration and '
                'ensures smooth performance.',
 'Each': '$ 51.70',
 'Info': '',
 'Line art': '',
 'Name': 'Stick-on Non-Vacuum Pads',
 'Product number': '9156107',
 'Technical specifications': '<p><strong>thickness: </strong>3/8 '
                             'in</p><p><strong>density: </strong>Medium</p>',
 'image_1': 'https://www.richelieu.com/documents/docsPr/91/56/10/7/9156107/1213344_700.jpg',
 'image_2': 'https://www.richelieu.com/documents/docsPr/91/56/10/7/9156107/1213346_700.jpg'}

{'Catalog link': '',
 'Category': 'Tools and Shop Supplies / Workshop Accessories / Tool '
             'Accessories / Sander Accessories',
 'Description': 'Size: 2-1/2" x 14".',
 'Each': '$ 12.36',
 'Info': '',
 'Line art': '',
 'Name': 'Sandpaper Belt 2½ " x 14" for Compact Belt Sander PC371 or PC371K',
 'Product number': 'PC371K060',
 'Technical specifications': '',
 'image_1': 'https://www.richelieu.com/documents/docsPr/PC/37/1K/06/0/PC371K060/1263523_700.jpg',
 '\xa0': '$ 148.18'}

{'Catalog link': '',
 'Category': 'Tools and Shop Supplies / Workshop Accessories / Tool '
             'Accessories / Sander Accessories',
 'Description': 'Size: 2-1/2" x 14".',
 'Each': '$ 12.36',
 'Info': '',
 'Line art': '',
 'Name': 'Sandpaper Belt 2½ " x 14" for Compact Belt Sander PC371 or PC371K',
 'Product number': 'PC371K080',
 'Technical specifications': '',
 'image_1': 'https://www.richelieu.com/documents/docsPr/PC/37/1K/08/0/PC371K080/1263524_700.jpg',
 '\xa0': '$ 148.18'}

{'Catalog link': '',
 'Category': 'Tools and Shop Supplies / Workshop Accessories / Tool '
             'Accessories / Sander Accessories',
 'Description': 'Size: 2-1/2" x 14".',
 'Each': '$ 12.36',
 'Info': '',
 'Line art': '',
 'Name': 'Sandpaper Belt 2½ " x 14" for Compact Belt Sander PC371 or PC371K',
 'Product number': 'PC371K120',
 'Technical specifications': '',
 'image_1': 'https://www.richelieu.com/documents/docsPr/PC/37/1K/12/0/PC371K120/1263526_700.jpg',
 '\xa0': '$ 148.18'}

{'Catalog link': '',
 'Category': 'Tools and Shop Supplies / Workshop Accessories / Tool '
             'Accessories / Sander Accessories',
 'Description': 'Size: 2-1/2" x 14".',
 'Each': '$ 12.36',
 'Info': '',
 'Line art': '',
 'Name': 'Sandpaper Belt 2½ " x 14" for Compact Belt Sander PC371 or PC371K',
 'Product number': 'PC371K100',
 'Technical specifications': '',
 'image_1': 'https://www.richelieu.com/documents/docsPr/PC/37/1K/10/0/PC371K100/1263525_700.jpg',
 '\xa0': '$ 148.18'}

{'Catalog link': '',
 'Category': 'Tools and Shop Supplies / Workshop Accessories / Tool '
             'Accessories / Sander Accessories',
 'Description': 'Exclusive single-piece hub design reduces pad vibration and '
                'ensures smooth performance.',
 'Each': '$ 25.22',
 'Info': '',
 'Line art': '',
 'Name': '5" Non-Vacuum Disc Pad Hook-Face',
 'Product number': '91454325T',
 'Technical specifications': '',
 'image_1': 'https://www.richelieu.com/documents/docsGr/120/107/7/1201077/1419678_700.jpg'}

{'Catalog link': '',
 'Category': 'Tools and Shop Supplies / Workshop Accessories / Tool '
             'Accessories / Sander Accessories',
 'Description': '- Pads mount with screws.',
 'Each': '$ 31.80',
 'Info': '',
 'Line art': '',
 'Name': 'Plates for Non-Vacuum (Grip-On) Dynabug II Disc Pads - 7.62 cm x '
         '10.79 cm (3" x 4-1/4")',
 'Product number': '9156315',
 'Technical specifications': '<p><strong>thickness: </strong>3/8 '
                             'in</p><p><strong>density: </strong>Medium</p>',
 'image_1': 'https://www.richelieu.com/documents/docsGr/116/625/4/1166254/1280825_700.jpg',
 '\xa0': '$ 179.95'}
```

Comment: I'm sure there's a better title that describes my problem, but I just couldn't think of a better one. Anyone is free to edit this accordingly

Comment: The solutions depends on how your original data looks like.

Comment: @MikeMüller updated.

Comment: Instead of using `writer.writerows`, can't you just use `writer.writerow` in a loop to write out the dictionaries one at a time?  If you want, you could explicitly flush the file every one in a while to ensure that data is written in the event of a crash.

Comment: @Iarsks no, I can't. Because for that to happen I'd still have to have all the dicts in that list. And the problem is: "What happens when you try to append the 6666 dict to that list and it crashes?" Not because there's an error, but because there's no more memory left...

Comment: how does your original data populate from, database, network, filesystem?

Comment: @DanielJ.Anderson network (scraping) :)

Comment: @Cajuu' is your envirment allow you to save temp data to database or disk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Temporary Saving Data

Since your data comes from scraping, it may be considered a stream.
To mimic a stream, I use `data_.pop()`to get one item at a time.
The following solution adds each item ones it comes form the stream.
The header and body of the csv are stored in different files.
The header potentially grows in length over time.
The the rows you saved before such a growth step naturally cannot know
this growth and therefore may be missing some trailing commas to indicate missing items.

```
import csv
import os

class StreamCSV:  # Python 3
    def __init__(self, header_file_name, body_file_name):
        self.header_file_name = header_file_name
        self.fbody = open(body_file_name, 'a', newline='', encoding='utf-8')
        self.csv_body = csv.writer(self.fbody)

    def add_item(self, item):
        if os.path.exists(self.header_file_name):
            with open(self.header_file_name, 'r', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as fobj:
                reader = csv.reader(fobj)
                try:
                    current_header = next(reader)
                except StopIteration:
                    current_header = []
        else:
            current_header = []
        header_set = set(current_header)
        for key in item:
            if key not in header_set:
                current_header.append(key)
        if len(header_set) < len(current_header):
            with open(self.header_file_name, 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as fobj:
                writer = csv.writer(fobj)
                writer.writerow(current_header)
        item_data = [item.get(head, '') for head in current_header]
        self.csv_body.writerow(item_data)
        self.fbody.flush()  # allows peeing into the file


if __name__ == '__main__':

    data_ = [
        {
            'a': '1',
            'b': '2',
            'c': '3',
        },
        {
            'a': '6',
            'd': '1',
            'b': '3',
        },
        {
            'c': '2',
            'e': '1',
            'f': '9',
        }
    ]

    def show_saved(file_names):
        for name in file_names:
            with open(name) as fobj:
                print(name)
                print(fobj.read())

    header_file_name, body_file_name = 'header.csv', 'body.csv'
    stream_writer = StreamCSV(header_file_name, body_file_name)

    for x in range(1, 4):
        print('step:', x)
        stream_writer.add_item(data_.pop())
        show_saved([header_file_name, body_file_name])
```

Output that shows the growth over time:

```
step: 1
header.csv
c,e,f

body.csv
2,1,9

step: 2
header.csv
c,e,f,a,d,b

body.csv
2,1,9
,,,6,1,3

step: 3
header.csv
c,e,f,a,d,b

body.csv
2,1,9
,,,6,1,3
3,,,1,,2
```

### Merging final results

You might want to merge header and body in an additional step, adding such missing trailing commas.

```
def merge_header_body(header_file_name, body_file_name, out_file_name):
    with open(header_file_name, 'r', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as fobj:
        reader = csv.reader(fobj)
        header = next(reader)

    with open(out_file_name, 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as fobj_out, \
    open(body_file_name, 'r', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as fobj_in:
        reader = csv.reader(fobj_in)
        writer = csv.writer(fobj_out)
        writer.writerow(header)
        target_length = len(header)
        for row in reader:
            diff = target_length - len(row)
            row.extend([''] * diff)
            writer.writerow(row)

out_file_name = 'merged.csv'
merge_header_body(header_file_name, body_file_name, out_file_name)
```

Content of `merged.csv`:

```
c,e,f,a,d,b
2,1,9,,,
,,,6,1,3
3,,,1,,2
```

### Crash Recovery

If the program crashes in between, it will resume.
Let's take the same data as before and add more rows:

```
for x in range(1, 4):
    print('step:', x)
    stream_writer.add_item(data_.pop())
    show_saved([header_file_name, body_file_name])
```

Output:

```
step: 1
header.csv
c,e,f,a,d,b

body.csv
2,1,9
,,,6,1,3
3,,,1,,2
2,1,9,,,

step: 2
header.csv
c,e,f,a,d,b

body.csv
2,1,9
,,,6,1,3
3,,,1,,2
2,1,9,,,
,,,6,1,3

step: 3
header.csv
c,e,f,a,d,b

body.csv
2,1,9
,,,6,1,3
3,,,1,,2
2,1,9,,,
,,,6,1,3
3,,,1,,2
```

Answer (score 4):

**Edit-1 26-Dec: Updated code to generate data based on your data**

Based on your requirements I would suggest the below

- Write headers in headers.csv file
- Write data in a data.csv file
- When you want to read/send this file, just merge the two files in one
- At start of your program read the existing headers.csv file and create field to index mapping
- When you encounter new keys in data you update the header map with a new index and update header.csv
- While writing dictionary data, you will use the header map to create the row data

Below is a quick/dirty POC of the same and it works well for me

```
import csv

try:
    f = open("headers.csv", mode="r+", encoding="utf-8")
except FileNotFoundError:
    f = open("headers.csv", mode="w+", encoding="utf-8")

f2 = open("data.csv", mode="a+", encoding="utf-8")
f.seek(0)
headers = f.readline().strip().split(",")
if headers == ['']:
    headers = []

headers_map = {}

for index, field in enumerate(headers):
    headers_map[field] = index


def update_header_dict(data):
    updated_headers = False
    for key in data.keys():
        if key not in headers_map:
            new_index = len(headers_map)
            headers_map[key] = new_index
            updated_headers = True

    if updated_headers:
        f.seek(0)
        csv.DictWriter(f, headers_map.keys()).writeheader()
        f.flush()


def get_row_data_dict(data):
    row_data = [""] * len(headers_map)

    for k, v in data.items():
        # if v and v[0] in ('=', '-'):
        #     # Mark the value as text, only needed if you want to display data in excel
        #     # else should be commented out
        #     v = "'" + v
        row_data[headers_map[k]] = v

    return row_data


def main(data):
    data_writer = csv.writer(f2)
    for row in data:
        update_header_dict(row)
        data_writer.writerow(get_row_data_dict(row))


data_ = [
    {'Catalog link': '',
     'Category': 'Tools and Shop Supplies / Workshop Accessories / Tool '
                 'Accessories / Sander Accessories',
     'Description': 'Exclusive single-piece hub design reduces pad vibration and '
                    'ensures smooth performance.',
     'Each': '$ 24.70',
     'Info': '',
     'Line art': '',
     'Name': '(5") Non-Vacuum Disc Pad Vinyl-Face',
     'Product number': '91456106T',
     'Technical specifications': '',
     'image_1': 'https://www.richelieu.com/documents/docsGr/120/107/6/1201076/1419675_700.jpg'},

    {'Catalog link': '',
     'Category': 'Tools and Shop Supplies / Workshop Accessories / Tool '
                 'Accessories / Sander Accessories',
     'Description': '',
     'Each': '$ 8.19',
     'Info': '<p><strong>material: </strong>Cork</p>',
     'Line art': '',
     'Name': 'Replacement Plate for MKT9924DB Belt Sander',
     'Product number': 'MKT4230358',
     'Technical specifications': '<p><strong>brand: </strong>Makita</p>',
     'image_1': 'https://www.richelieu.com/documents/docsGr/116/631/4/1166314/1281513_700.jpg',
     '\xa0': '$ 257.80'},

    {'Catalog link': '',
     'Category': 'Tools and Shop Supplies / Workshop Accessories / Tool '
                 'Accessories / Sander Accessories',
     'Description': '',
     'Each': '$ 8.19',
     'Info': '<p><strong>material: </strong>Graphite</p>',
     'Line art': '',
     'Name': 'Replacement Plate for MKT9924DB Belt Sander',
     'Product number': 'MKT4230366',
     'Technical specifications': '<p><strong>brand: </strong>Makita</p>',
     'image_1': 'https://www.richelieu.com/documents/docsPr/MK/T4/23/03/66/MKT4230366/1281514_700.jpg',
     '\xa0': '$ 257.80'},

    {'Catalog link': '',
     'Category': 'Tools and Shop Supplies / Workshop Accessories / Tool '
                 'Accessories / Sander Accessories',
     'Description': '- Exclusive single-piece hub design reduces pad vibration and '
                    'ensures smooth performance.',
     'Each': '$ 38.47',
     'Info': '',
     'Line art': '',
     'Name': 'Non-Grip Vacuum Pads',
     'Product number': '9154325',
     'Technical specifications': '<p><strong>thickness: </strong>3/8 '
                                 'in</p><p><strong>density: '
                                 '</strong>Medium</p><p><strong>nap: '
                                 '</strong>Short</p>',
     'image_1': 'https://www.richelieu.com/documents/docsPr/91/54/32/5/9154325/1213330_700.jpg',
     'image_2': 'https://www.richelieu.com/documents/docsPr/91/54/32/5/9154325/1213331_700.jpg'},

    {'Catalog link': '',
     'Category': 'Tools and Shop Supplies / Workshop Accessories / Tool '
                 'Accessories / Sander Accessories',
     'Description': '- Exclusive single-piece hub design reduces pad vibration and '
                    'ensures smooth performance.',
     'Each': '$ 52.92',
     'Info': '',
     'Line art': '',
     'Name': 'Non-Grip Vacuum Pads',
     'Product number': '9154327',
     'Technical specifications': '<p><strong>thickness: </strong>3/8 '
                                 'in</p><p><strong>density: '
                                 '</strong>Medium</p><p><strong>nap: '
                                 '</strong>Short</p>',
     'image_1': 'https://www.richelieu.com/documents/docsGr/105/122/1/1051221/1213328_700.jpg',
     'image_2': 'https://www.richelieu.com/documents/docsPr/91/54/32/7/9154327/1213332_700.jpg'},

    {'Catalog link': '',
     'Category': 'Tools and Shop Supplies / Workshop Accessories / Tool '
                 'Accessories / Sander Accessories',
     'Description': '- Unique one-piece hub design reduces pad vibration and '
                    'ensures smooth performance.',
     'Each': '$ 26.84',
     'Info': '',
     'Line art': '',
     'Name': 'Stick-on Non-Vacuum Pads',
     'Product number': '9156106',
     'Technical specifications': '<p><strong>thickness: </strong>3/8 '
                                 'in</p><p><strong>density: </strong>Medium</p>',
     'image_1': 'https://www.richelieu.com/documents/docsGr/105/122/4/1051224/1213343_700.jpg',
     'image_2': 'https://www.richelieu.com/documents/docsPr/91/56/10/6/9156106/1213345_700.jpg'},

    {'Catalog link': '',
     'Category': 'Tools and Shop Supplies / Workshop Accessories / Tool '
                 'Accessories / Sander Accessories',
     'Description': '- Unique one-piece hub design reduces pad vibration and '
                    'ensures smooth performance.',
     'Each': '$ 51.70',
     'Info': '',
     'Line art': '',
     'Name': 'Stick-on Non-Vacuum Pads',
     'Product number': '9156107',
     'Technical specifications': '<p><strong>thickness: </strong>3/8 '
                                 'in</p><p><strong>density: </strong>Medium</p>',
     'image_1': 'https://www.richelieu.com/documents/docsPr/91/56/10/7/9156107/1213344_700.jpg',
     'image_2': 'https://www.richelieu.com/documents/docsPr/91/56/10/7/9156107/1213346_700.jpg'},

    {'Catalog link': '',
     'Category': 'Tools and Shop Supplies / Workshop Accessories / Tool '
                 'Accessories / Sander Accessories',
     'Description': 'Size: 2-1/2" x 14".',
     'Each': '$ 12.36',
     'Info': '',
     'Line art': '',
     'Name': 'Sandpaper Belt 2½ " x 14" for Compact Belt Sander PC371 or PC371K',
     'Product number': 'PC371K060',
     'Technical specifications': '',
     'image_1': 'https://www.richelieu.com/documents/docsPr/PC/37/1K/06/0/PC371K060/1263523_700.jpg',
     '\xa0': '$ 148.18'},

    {'Catalog link': '',
     'Category': 'Tools and Shop Supplies / Workshop Accessories / Tool '
                 'Accessories / Sander Accessories',
     'Description': 'Size: 2-1/2" x 14".',
     'Each': '$ 12.36',
     'Info': '',
     'Line art': '',
     'Name': 'Sandpaper Belt 2½ " x 14" for Compact Belt Sander PC371 or PC371K',
     'Product number': 'PC371K080',
     'Technical specifications': '',
     'image_1': 'https://www.richelieu.com/documents/docsPr/PC/37/1K/08/0/PC371K080/1263524_700.jpg',
     '\xa0': '$ 148.18'},

    {'Catalog link': '',
     'Category': 'Tools and Shop Supplies / Workshop Accessories / Tool '
                 'Accessories / Sander Accessories',
     'Description': 'Size: 2-1/2" x 14".',
     'Each': '$ 12.36',
     'Info': '',
     'Line art': '',
     'Name': 'Sandpaper Belt 2½ " x 14" for Compact Belt Sander PC371 or PC371K',
     'Product number': 'PC371K120',
     'Technical specifications': '',
     'image_1': 'https://www.richelieu.com/documents/docsPr/PC/37/1K/12/0/PC371K120/1263526_700.jpg',
     '\xa0': '$ 148.18'},

    {'Catalog link': '',
     'Category': 'Tools and Shop Supplies / Workshop Accessories / Tool '
                 'Accessories / Sander Accessories',
     'Description': 'Size: 2-1/2" x 14".',
     'Each': '$ 12.36',
     'Info': '',
     'Line art': '',
     'Name': 'Sandpaper Belt 2½ " x 14" for Compact Belt Sander PC371 or PC371K',
     'Product number': 'PC371K100',
     'Technical specifications': '',
     'image_1': 'https://www.richelieu.com/documents/docsPr/PC/37/1K/10/0/PC371K100/1263525_700.jpg',
     '\xa0': '$ 148.18'},

    {'Catalog link': '',
     'Category': 'Tools and Shop Supplies / Workshop Accessories / Tool '
                 'Accessories / Sander Accessories',
     'Description': 'Exclusive single-piece hub design reduces pad vibration and '
                    'ensures smooth performance.',
     'Each': '$ 25.22',
     'Info': '',
     'Line art': '',
     'Name': '5" Non-Vacuum Disc Pad Hook-Face',
     'Product number': '91454325T',
     'Technical specifications': '',
     'image_1': 'https://www.richelieu.com/documents/docsGr/120/107/7/1201077/1419678_700.jpg'},

    {'Catalog link': '',
     'Category': 'Tools and Shop Supplies / Workshop Accessories / Tool '
                 'Accessories / Sander Accessories',
     'Description': '- Pads mount with screws.',
     'Each': '$ 31.80',
     'Info': '',
     'Line art': '',
     'Name': 'Plates for Non-Vacuum (Grip-On) Dynabug II Disc Pads - 7.62 cm x '
             '10.79 cm (3" x 4-1/4")',
     'Product number': '9156315',
     'Technical specifications': '<p><strong>thickness: </strong>3/8 '
                                 'in</p><p><strong>density: </strong>Medium</p>',
     'image_1': 'https://www.richelieu.com/documents/docsGr/116/625/4/1166254/1280825_700.jpg',
     '\xa0': '$ 179.95'}
]

data2_ = [
    {
        'a': '2',
        'f': '1',
        'z': '9',
    },
]

main(data_)
# main(data2_)

f.close()
f2.close()
```

Running above generates two files and then i run below on terminal

```
cat headers.csv data.csv > output.csv
```

And then open `output.csv` in excel

[image: Excel Data]

The only issue you may see is `#NAME?`, but those are because excel is trying to process the `-` you had at the start of the text. If you to process text like that you need to uncomment the below part of the code

```
    # if v and v[0] in ('=', '-'):
    #     # Mark the value as text, only needed if you want to display data in excel
    #     # else should be commented out
    #     v = "'" + v
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That's a nice idea but unfortunately if I run your version against mine, the result is different :)

Comment: Can you explain that? What do you mean by `your version against mine`?

Comment: Run my version and then run yours. See if the result is the same

Comment: @Cajuu', updated the code and result with your example data

Answer (score 2):

[As it was said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47914844/avoid-bulk-data-export-into-csv-when-the-header-is-dynamic#comment82866063_47914844), I would use a "write-to-file" per row(s) with flushing mechanisms system. If you don't mind using [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/), the simplest way IMHO, would be to change your `main` function as following :

```
def main(data):
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    for item in data:
        df_current = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(item, orient='index').T
        df = df.append(df_current)
        df.to_csv(RESULT_FILE, index=False)
```

This way you are updating your `RESULT_FILE` with a freshly updated `DataFrame` without having to know the complete header.

For further performance enhancements, you can add a condition to write the file every `n` set of data :

```
def main(data):
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    chunksize = 5
    for i, item in enumerate(data):
        df_c = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(item, orient='index').T
        df = df.append(df_c)
        if ((i%chunksize)==0 or i==(len(data)-1)):
            df.to_csv(RESULT_FILE, index=False)
```

As for the [memory issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47914844/avoid-bulk-data-export-into-csv-when-the-header-is-dynamic#comment82866332_47914844), I'd suggest you use [iterators over lists](https://stackoverflow.com/a/631619/6468869) for the initial scrapped `data` passed to this function to reduce memory consumption.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it's a bit over the top, however it was to me the easiest way to solve your issue.  It leverages sqlite and the ability to add columns to the table as you go.  Also, I didn't exhaustively test it.

```
#!/bin/env python
from os import path

import sqlite3
import atexit

how_many = 0


class DB(object):
    db_file = "data.db"

    def __init__(self):
        self._fieldnames = set(["ignore_field"])
        self._cursor = None
        self._db_conn = None
        create = False

        if not path.isfile(self.db_file):
            create = True
        self._db_conn = sqlite3.connect(self.db_file)
        self._cursor = self._db_conn.cursor()

        if create:
            self._cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE data (ignore_field integer)""")
        else:
            # retrieve already existing fieldnames so we can continue
            pragma = self._db_conn.execute("pragma table_info('data')").fetchall()
            self._fieldnames = set([x[1] for x in pragma])

    def _add_fields(self, field_list):
        for field in field_list:
            if field not in self._fieldnames:
                self._cursor.execute("alter table data add column '%s' 'TEXT'" % field)
                self._fieldnames.add(field)

    def _insert_data(self, data):
        fields = []
        values = []
        for f, v in data.iteritems():
            fields.append(f)
            values.append("'{}'".format(v))
        sql = """insert into data ({}) values ({})""".format(", ".join(fields), ", ".join(values))
        self._db_conn.execute(sql)

    def consume(self, one_dict):
        self._add_fields(one_dict.keys())
        self._insert_data(one_dict)
        self._db_conn.commit()

    def csv_out(self):
        self._cursor.execute("select * from data")
        header = [x[0] for x in self._cursor.description]
        print(",".join(header))
        for row in self._cursor:
            out = []
            for field in row:
                out.append(field if field else "")
            print(",".join(out))


def cleanup(total):
    print("Ended after record {}/{}".format(how_many, total))


def main(data):
    global how_many
    atexit.register(cleanup, len(data))

    db = DB()

    skip = False
    if how_many:
        skip = how_many

    for each in data:
        if not skip:
            db.consume(each)
        else:
            skip -= 1
            if not skip:
                print("Finished skipping {} records.".format(how_many))

        how_many += 1

    print("Completed loading available data.")

    db.csv_out()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    data_ = [
        {
            'a': '1',
            'b': '2',
            'c': '3',
        },
        {
            'a': '6',
            'd': '1',
            'b': '3',
        },
        {
            'c': '2',
            'e': '1',
            'f': '9',
        }
    ]

    main(data_)
```

If you modify how_many then the main loop skips that many records.  This lets you recover from a crash as the atexit hook should tell you how far the program got.

There's also a bogus column/field name since you can't create an empty table and I went lazy and didn't tie the table creation into the first iteration of DB.consume().  You can always replace "ignore_field" with one of your existing fields.

More laziness, I didn't do file IO I just print out the CSV.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it kind of doesn't work. I get: `sqlite3.OperationalError: table data has no column named d`

Comment: Apparently it throws this error when running your version the first time. After running it the second time it somehow works.

Comment: Sorry about that, it's line 14, corrected above.  I did set("ignore_field") and it should have been either {"ignore_field"} or set(["ignore_field"])

Comment: The other thing is that this still stores the field names in a list which given little enough RAM or a large enough collection of data can still exhaust your memory and go no further.  The addition of columns to the DB can be done without maintaining the list, it's just going to be a lot slower since you'd query the DB for what columns exist for every row of data added.