# Why not make all iterables their own multiple pass iterators?

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterator, iteration, iterable

I'm new to Python, but my understanding of iterables and iterators in Python is that they support the iterator protocol.

In some iteration tool/context, an iterable is passed to `iter()` to return an iterator. Then, `next()` is called successively to generate all items until `next()` raises the `StopIteration` exception.

An iterator will support only one pass of iteration, while an iterable that is not its own iterator will support multiple passes.

It seems like doing away with the distinction between an iterable and iterator, making all iterables their own multiple pass iterators, would be cleaner.

What is the benefit/logic of separating iterable and iterator in the iterator protocol?

Comment: The iterator keeps the *state* (like the current index for sequences) of the iteration. Clearly, the iter*able* cannot maintain its own iteration state as you want to be able to have e.g. multiple concurrent iterations over the same iterable. Each of those iteration processes needs its own track keeping object -- the iterator.

Comment: Here's a question&answer over [iterators vs. iterables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/628903/performance-advantages-to-iterators).  A key advantage of iterators is space performance (i.e. less memory sincee not holding onto the entire dataset).

Comment: "An iterator will support only one pass of iteration, while an iterable that is not its own iterator will support multiple passes." => because it yields a new iterator each time you start a new iteration.

Comment: Because it de-couples the act of *traversing* a collection from the collection itself.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Yes, I understand that that's the protocol. To rephrase my question: why not make `next()` available to the iterable, instead of creating an iterator from `iter()`, then calling `next()`?

Comment: @bhpaak because it would force the iterable to be it's own iterator, which would make iteration state management uselessly complex and prevent reentrancy. Decoupliing the iterator (responsability; iterating over an iterable) from the iterable itself (responsability: providing an iterator) solves those issue. It's a very standard design pattern FWIW.

Comment: Also note that in practice, you very seldom use `iter()` and `next()``directly - you just iterate over your iterable and let the runtime take care of the gory details, so it's pretty transparent.

Answer (score 0):

An [iterable](https://docs.python.org/3.8/glossary.html#term-iterable) means the object can be iterated over. Usually, that means iter() can be called on the instance to get an iterator.

An [iterator](https://docs.python.org/3.8/glossary.html#term-iterator) is an object which iterates. They are also an iterable, meaning they can be called in iter() and return...themselves. By calling next() on it, the iterator returns the next object in the sequence.

Simply: all iterables and iterators give an iterator when called with iter(). All iterators give the next element in a sequence when called with next().

Iterators are single-pass because it makes the programmer's life easier. This can be passed as an iterator: `(x*3 for x in range(10))`

So can this:

```
__iter__(self):
    for x in range(10):
        yield x*3
```

If they had to be multipass, each would have to be programmed inside another loop, adding more work to the programmer of the iterator.

If you want to pass again, get a new iterator from the iterable when the iterator runs out of elements to return. :)