# Why would an earlier print statement cause different downstream results when commented out?

Tags: python, iterator

I'm messing around with zipping 3 lists together and then unpacking them in Python to better understand lists and `zip()`. In the code below, if I don't comment out `print(list(zip_list))`, the unzip1-3 variables produce empty lists. If i do comment that part out, i get the lists I would expect. Why would this be?

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3]
list2 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
list3 = ['!', '@', '#']

zip_list = zip(list1, list2, list3)
print(list(zip_list))

unzip1 = []
unzip2 = []
unzip3 = []

for i, j, k in zip_list:
    unzip1.append(i)
    unzip2.append(j)
    unzip3.append(k)

print(unzip1)
print(unzip2)
print(unzip3)
```

Output:

```
[(1, 'a', '!'), (2, 'b', '@'), (3, 'c', '#')]
[]
[]
[]
```

Output, commented out:

```
[1, 2, 3]
['a', 'b', 'c']
['!', '@', '#']
```

Comment: Note that `zip` is a generator, and `list(zip_list)` consumes it, thus, your iterator is empty afterwards

Comment: @C.Nivs To be pedantic, it's an iterator but not a generator

Comment: @C.Nivs - that does! I didn’t realize that .zip() didn’t just create a new list. It makes sense that the statement basically clears the iterator

Comment: Can I ask, why would we only want to use the iterator once? I’m obviously new to this, but what is the thought behind “consuming” the iterator only once?

Comment: @dele2111 See [Performance Advantages to Iterators?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/628903/4518341) tl;dr it's more efficient for large amounts of data

Comment: Ok that makes sense. Basically if we have a large set it's better to just iterate and get our result than to do that plus store that data in a list. I think as a beginner I am focused solely on syntax and not necessarily on application. Thanks for your help!